# Can rooting remove all malware, viruses and backdoors?

Tags: applications, rooting, malware

I ask this question because I read somewhere that there was a Chinese smartphone with in-built malware which could not removed even by rooting.

(I searched the article everywhere but couldn't find it. So, no source. Sorry!)

**Is there a possibility that any kind of malware or virus, that could harm your device and/or your privacy, will remain even after rooting your device?**

**EDIT:** By rooting, I actually meant rooting **and** then flashing a custom ROM, i.e, reinstall android. Sorry for the confusion.

Can malware and viruses persist after this?

Comment: Probably my question is related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164880/how-do-i-fix-malware-installed-automatically-in-the-system-directory

Comment: Maybe this is the news article you're talking about: [Chinese-authored spyware found on more than 700 million Android phones](https://www.cyberscoop.com/android-malware-china-huawei-zte-kryptowire-blu-products/)

Answer (score 1):

Even after installing custom ROMs some area on the internal storage is left unchanged and if the malware resides in that area of the internal storage it won't be deleted even after you flash a new ROM **but** it is a very rare case when a malware goes so deep into the system.
If you want another example for this then try to install a boot logo (i know it isn't a malware) but even after you flash 100s of ROMs it will never change the boot logo of your device and this proves that some code remains unchanged even after flashing new ROMs

Comment: What area that are both unchanged between flashes _and_ stores executable stuff could affect userspace? Boot logo is a bad example as it strictly accepts files of very specific format. `/data` and `/system` are wiped when installing a ROM. `/tmp` and many are only generated on each boot.

Comment: Is there a way to clean **everything**?

Comment: What are bootkits? Obad? Oldboot? 
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/601716/recurring-malware-immediately-after-factory-reset/?p=3905554
Can bootkits persist even after reinstallation of OS?
Are these what you were talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Rooting allows you to modify the system and access all app data. It does not change anything regarding already installed installed malware or virus.

If you have rooted the device using an exploit the installed malware may also use this exploit to get root access.

Conclusion: If your device is infected delete it and reinstall an untainted system/image. However advanced malware may even survive a installation of a new ROM potentially in partitions that are not erased or in flash roms of embedded chips.

Therefore the only 100% secure way to get rid of malware is to physically shred your device. No device - no malware.

Comment: What I actually meant to say was: rooting followed by flashing. Sorry! Can this ensure that **all** malware, viruses and backdoors are removed?

Comment: What are bootkits? Obad? Oldboot? 

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/601716/recurring-malware-immediately-after-factory-reset/?p=3905554
Can bootkits persist even after reinstallation of OS?

Answer (score 0):

Rooting doesn't have anything to do with removing malware. Rooting is process when you get a superuser on your phone so you have full control over device (like accessing all files and folders etc.) What you can do is to remove system apps. And those chinese phones had malware probably on kernel level or built in into system, not as application.

Comment: How do I remove malware at the kernel level or built-in into a system? Will reinstallation suffice?

Comment: @Stack-Boi You can remove it with flashing custom rom in which malware is removed.

Comment: Can **all** malware be removed by flashing custom ROM? This was the question I originally intended to ask.

Comment: What are bootkits? Obad? Oldboot?

Comment: @Stack-Boi Maybe, maybe not you'll know when you try it's not exact science